# How to filter data parsed from database using ASP

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, asp-classic, adodb

I've recently got my hands on an ASP project that was quite a mess. I'm not familiar with the language but after spending some time searching the Internet I've managed to learn it but I'm still unfamiliar with the database queries etc.

So here's the problem, I've got this code that gets data from an MS Access database file. What I want is to filter this data based on the post/get parameters passed.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tyres"

if len(brand1) > 2 then 
     sql = sql & " WHERE brand = '" & brand1 & "' AND application = '" & season1 & "'"

if len(brand2) > 2 then 
     sql = sql & " or brand = '" & brand2 & "' AND application = '" & season2 & "'"

if len(brand3) > 2 then 
    sql = sql & " or brand = '" & brand3 & "' AND application = '" & season3 & "'"

if len(brand4) > 2 then 
    sql = sql & " or brand = '" & brand4 & "' AND application = '" & season4 & "'"

if len(brand5) > 2 then 
    sql = sql & " or brand = '" & brand5 & "' AND application = '" & season5 & "'"

set Dataconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Dataconn.Open "database-in"
set DataTable = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
DataTable.Open sql, Dataconn
```

And it doesn't seems to work. Note that the user is able to insert up to 5 (as you can see) different parameters in order to search for the products in the db. So if you have any further info on how to make this work feel free to suggest.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to throw away your code. One does **never** build SQL statements by concatenating strings. Doing this is going to result in run-time errors and bugs at best, and SQL injection attacks at worst.

Comment: Another observation is that you have counted variable names (`brand1` .. `brandN` and `season1` .. `seasonN`). That means you actually want an arrays named `brand` and `season` here. Show how these variables are currently created.

Comment: @Tomalak well, actually is kinda more complicated. I want each one to be a separated array of results. For example, i want to get result based on brand1 AND season1, then brand2 AND season2 etc. without each one mixing with the other

Comment: That's not a problem at all. But first you really need to get rid of the counted variables and the code duplication that comes along with them.

Comment: @Tomalak what do you mean by that? I have 5 different inputs, that will filter the data

Comment: I assume the inputs are `<select>` boxes and the user always picks `brand` and `season` pairs?

Comment: @Tomalak there's one text input and two different checkbox inputs (brand, season).

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unwise to create SQL from string concatenation, and even right-out [dangerous](https://xkcd.com/327/) if those strings partly come from user input.

Database libraries such as ADODB have [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/command-object-ado) and [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado) for this situation. They use a fixed SQL string with placeholders and the library makes sure that nothing bad can happen, no matter what the user-supplied values may be.

This also means we can prepare an SQL statement up-front and re-use it many times throughout the lifetime of the page.

```vb
Dim Conn ' As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd  ' As ADODB.Command

Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\path\to\your\database.accdb;"

' prepare a reusable command with parameters (i.e. placeholders)
With Cmd
  Set .ActiveConnection = Conn
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 WHERE brand = @brand AND application = @season"

  ' set up the parameters for each placeholder
  '  - use proper datatypes here, as per your DB
  '  - varchar types need a defined length
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@brand", adVarChar, , 50)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@season", adVarChar, , 100)
End With

' helper function that operates the Command object and returns a RecordSet
Function SearchTyres(brand, season)
  Cmd.Parameters("@brand", brand)
  Cmd.Parameters("@season", season)
  Set SearchTyres = Cmd.Execute
End With
```

It's convenient to be able to use the ADODB-specific constants such as `adCmdText` or `adVarChar` in your code. To have them available anywhere without fuss, you need to declare the ADODB type library in your `global.asa` file (create one if you don't have it), adding this to the top of the file:

```html
<!--metadata 
    type="TypeLib" 
    name="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" 
    uuid="B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129"
    version="6.1"
-->
```

Now you can use this in your page, for example:

```vb
If Len(brand1) > 2 Then
  With SearchTyres(brand1, season1)
    ' ...let's do something with the RecordSet
    While Not .EOF
      Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(!Field1) & "<br>"
      .MoveNext
    Wend
  End With
End If
```

Notes

- Don't do `SELECT *` - always write out the fields you want to have.
- Declaring the type library is not strictly necessary, but if you don't, then you have to define all the constants like `adVarChar` yourself, and that's much more hassle than it's worth.
- `With SearchTyres(...)` is convenience shorthand for

  ```
  Dim Rs
  Set Rs = SearchTyres(...)
  With Rs
    ' ...
  End With
  ```
- `Rs!Field1` is convenience shorthand for `Rs.Fields("Field1")`. Inside a `With Rs` block, the `Rs` itself is optional, so a plain `!Field1` is actually meaningful.
- Lastly, it can help to create code in the VBA IDE of an MS Office product (such as Word). Use Tools/References to reference the same ADODB type library. VBA and VBS are not 100 code-compatible, but the VBA IDE has Intellisense, a proper debugger, uses the same objects and code can be transferred to ASP with minimal changes.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, the problem here is that the values passed from the checkboxes are not wrapped in single quotes (so i can use WHERE ... IN statement).. I tried to use Split() function but it creates many lines of code. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You are still thinking in *"SQL is a string and I need single quotes"* terms. You don't need single quotes, not in a `WHERE ... IN` statement and not anywhere else. You need parameters.

Comment: I see! Thanks, i 'll give it a try! :)

Comment: Using `IN` in a prepared statement is a bit more complex, because the number of parameters needed is no longer fixed and known ahead of time. But it's definitely doable. For example If there are three values, your prepared SQL string in the Command object needs to look something like this: `... WHERE field IN (?, ?, ?)` and your need to call `.Parameters.Append` three times.

Comment: Yeah but in this situation the number of parameters vary from 1 to 15-16 with each user selecting different number of parameters. For example, there are 13 brands but one user might select 2 brands, another one might select 4, etc...

Comment: @Citer that's fine you will always know how many you have when submitted, just need to build the `IN (?, ?, ...)` dynamically based on how many you have then use a `For Each` loop to call `.Parameter.Append` the same number of times.

Comment: @Tomalak not sure how many answers need to be posted going over this stuff, it's all been covered before. Also named parameters won't work, you need to use `?` ordinal placeholders in the SQL when using `adCmdText`. Should be `SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 WHERE brand = ? AND application = ?`

Comment: Hm, named parameters definitely work, I've tried just to make sure. Apart from that, this is not the only category of questions that has been explained to death. In fact, it's probably *still* a niche topic in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @Tomalak guess it depends on the database provider, I know they work with `adCmdStoredProc` but usually `adCmdText` requires `?` placeholders.

Answer (score -3):

Since everyone else is busy bashing you instead of actually answering your question of how to build your sql string:

```
<%

    SqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Tyres WHERE 1 = 1 " 
    If Len(brand1) > 2 OR  Len(brand2) > 2 OR  Len(brand3) > 2 OR  Len(brand4) > 2 OR  Len(brand5) > 2 Then
        BrandInStr = " AND brand IN("
            If Len(brand1) > 2 Then
                BrandInStr = BrandInStr & "'" & brand1 & "',"    
            End If          
            If Len(brand2) > 2 Then
                BrandInStr = BrandInStr & "'" & brand2 & "',"    
            End If              
            If Len(brand3) > 2 Then
                BrandInStr = BrandInStr & "'" & brand3 & "',"    
            End If              
            If Len(brand4) > 2 Then
                BrandInStr = BrandInStr & "'" & brand4 & "',"    
            End If                  
            If Len(brand5) > 2 Then
                BrandInStr = BrandInStr & "'" & brand5 & "',"    
            End If  
        BrandInStr = Left(BrandInStr,Len(BrandInStr)-1)             
        BrandInStr = BrandInStr & ") "
    End If
    If Len(season1) > 2 OR  Len(season2) > 2 OR  Len(season3) > 2 OR  Len(season4) > 2 OR  Len(season5) > 2 Then
        SeasonInStr = " AND Season IN("
            If Len(Season1) > 2 Then
                SeasonInStr = SeasonInStr & "'" & Season1 & "',"    
            End If          
            If Len(Season2) > 2 Then
                SeasonInStr = SeasonInStr & "'" & Season2 & "',"    
            End If              
            If Len(Season3) > 2 Then
                SeasonInStr = SeasonInStr & "'" & Season3 & "',"    
            End If              
            If Len(Season4) > 2 Then
                SeasonInStr = SeasonInStr & "'" & Season4 & "',"    
            End If      
            If Len(Season5) > 2 Then
                SeasonInStr = SeasonInStr & "'" & Season5 & "',"  
            End If  
        SeasonInStr = Left(SeasonInStr,Len(SeasonInStr)-1)              
        SeasonInStr = SeasonInStr & ") "
    End If

    SqlStr = SqlStr & BrandInStr & " " & SeasonInStr

%>
```

However if your variables are passed as a single comma delimeted string (instead of numbered) it would be much easier

```
<%

    SqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Tyres WHERE 1 = 1 "

    If Len(Trim(Replace(Replace(Brand," ",""),",","") > 0 Then
       SqlStr = SqlStr & "AND Brand In('" & Replace(Brand,",","','") & "') "
    End If


    If Len(Trim(Replace(Replace(Season," ",""),",","") > 0 Then
       SqlStr = SqlStr & "AND Season In('" & Replace(Season,",","','") & "') "
    End If

%>
```

Comment: Shame the advice you have given is absolutely the one thing you shouldn't do.

Comment: Maybe, when people seem to be bashing a thing excessively, maybe that thing is a bad idea.